# How to fix Foreign key cascade delete/update exceeds max depth of 15 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a record with id = 1.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `job_id`(`job`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 21 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;


INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (4, 3);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (5, 4);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (6, 5);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (7, 6);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (8, 7);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (9, 8);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (10, 9);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (11, 10);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (12, 11);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (13, 12);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (14, 13);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (15, 14);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (16, 15);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (17, 16);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (18, 17);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (19, 18);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (20, 19);
```

DELETE FROM test WHERE id = 1;

Error: Foreign key cascade delete/update exceeds max depth of 15.

Answer (score 2):

you can not , it is [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html) restriction

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same
> table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like
> RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE
> CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite
> loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential ON DELETE
> SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON
> DELETE CASCADE. **Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15
> levels deep**.